# Why template function cannot be a friend template function of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I was following a video tutorial and I want to declare a template function as a friend of a template class. I don't know why code is throwing error.

```
template<class T>class C;
template<class T>void doSomething2(T);
template<class T>class C{
    int b;
    friend void doSomething2(T);

};
template<class U>void doSomething2(U u){
    C<U> obj;
    obj.b=100;
}
int main()
{
    C<int> obj;
    int a=44;
    doSomething2(a);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiler was throwing error.

Error :

> templates_friends_38.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void doSomething2(T) [with T = int]’:
>   templates_friends_38.cpp:40:19:   required from here
>   templates_friends_38.cpp:32:9: error: ‘int C::b’ is private within this context
>        obj.b=100;
>        ~~~~^
>   templates_friends_38.cpp:25:9: note: declared private here
>        int b;
>            ^

Comment: Do you want all `doSomething2<U>` to be `friend`? Or any `doSomething2<C<U>>`? Or only `doSomething2<C<T>>` or `doSomething2<T>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I wanted first one to be a friend. what did you mean by other functions?

Comment: You have `template <class T> class C;` and `template<class U>void doSomething2(U)` (where `T` and `U` might be equal or not or have some other relation). `doSomething2<int>` might want to use `C<float>` for example. As syntax would be a little different between those different variant.

Comment: No, I assumed they were same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `<>` in a friend declaration to specify that doSomething2 is a template function:

```
template<class T>class C;
template<class T>void doSomething2(T);
template<class T>class C{
    int b;
    friend void doSomething2<>(T);

};
template<class U>void doSomething2(U u){
    C<U> obj;
    obj.b=100;
}
int main()
{
    C<int> obj;
    int a=44;
    doSomething2(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`friend void doSomething2(T);`, you're declaring a new non-template function named `doSomething2` as `friend`, which is not the one you expected.

You need to specify that `doSomething2` is a function template, e.g.

```
friend void doSomething2<T>(T);
//                      ^^^
```

Or take advantage of template argument deduction and just write

```
friend void doSomething2<>(T);
//                      ^^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Evk1fFx2AFf75k8)